# Prove there is a largest Lebesgue number for a cover

Tags: general-topology

This is Exercise 4 in Chapter 1.5 of Introduction to topology by Gamelin.

Let ${U_\alpha}$ be a finite open cover of a compact metric space X.

(a) Show that there exists $\epsilon$ > 0 such that for each x $\in$ X, the open ball B(x;$\epsilon$) is contained in one of the $U_\alpha$'s.
Such an $\epsilon$ is called a Lebesgue number of the cover.

(b) Show that if at least one of the $U_\alpha$'s is a proper subset of X, then there is a largest Legesgue number for the cover.

I can prove Part(a) using contradiction. However, I am quite confused about Part(b). If one of the $U_\alpha$'s is the metric space X, would the Lebesgue number be unbounded because any open ball will be contained in X?

Comment: The condition says "if at least one of the $U_{\alpha}$ is a proper subset of $X$"...

Comment: This cannot be true. If one of the $U_\alpha = X$, then there is no largest Lebesgue number (since **each** $B(x;\epsilon) \subset X$). Thus you should  assume that all $U_\alpha \ne X$.